# SQL Server Restore Failing with Error Read on "M:\MSSQL\My_FULL_Backup_20190924_010558.bak" failed: 1101(A tape access reached a filemark

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2017

I have been trying to restore one of our db for the past few days without any luck. I keep getting the below error. I tried the restore during peak hours, off peak hours both by accessing the backup via network and then moving the file to local server.

I have also run Restorefilelistonly and restoreheaderonly on the backup and all seems to be fine. There is no permissions issue.

Please see the error below and the screenshot from SQL Logs. I did not find much help googling this issue.

```
1 percent processed.
2 percent processed.
3 percent processed.
4 percent processed.
5 percent processed.
6 percent processed.
7 percent processed.
8 percent processed.
9 percent processed.
10 percent processed.
11 percent processed.
12 percent processed.
13 percent processed.
14 percent processed.
15 percent processed.
16 percent processed.
17 percent processed.
18 percent processed.
19 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
21 percent processed.
22 percent processed.
23 percent processed.
24 percent processed.
25 percent processed.
26 percent processed.
27 percent processed.
28 percent processed.
29 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
31 percent processed.
32 percent processed.
33 percent processed.
34 percent processed.
35 percent processed.
36 percent processed.
37 percent processed.
38 percent processed.
39 percent processed.
40 percent processed.
41 percent processed.
42 percent processed.
43 percent processed.
44 percent processed.
45 percent processed.
46 percent processed.
47 percent processed.
48 percent processed.
49 percent processed.
50 percent processed.
51 percent processed.
52 percent processed.
53 percent processed.
54 percent processed.
55 percent processed.
56 percent processed.
57 percent processed.
58 percent processed.
59 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
61 percent processed.
62 percent processed.
63 percent processed.
64 percent processed.
65 percent processed.
66 percent processed.
67 percent processed.
68 percent processed.
69 percent processed.
70 percent processed.
71 percent processed.
72 percent processed.
73 percent processed.
74 percent processed.
75 percent processed.
76 percent processed.
77 percent processed.
78 percent processed.
79 percent processed.
80 percent processed.
81 percent processed.
82 percent processed.
83 percent processed.
84 percent processed.
85 percent processed.
86 percent processed.
87 percent processed.
88 percent processed.
89 percent processed.
90 percent processed.
91 percent processed.
92 percent processed.
93 percent processed.
94 percent processed.
95 percent processed.
96 percent processed.
97 percent processed.
98 percent processed.
Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Read on "M:\MSSQL\My_FULL_Backup_20190924_010558.bak" failed: 1101(A tape access reached a filemark.)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

[image]

Restore command used:

```
USE [master] RESTORE DATABASE [XXXXX_Testing_20190910] FROM DISK = N'M:\MSSQL\USE1-PRD-CL4$Entreprise_AG2_Testing_FULL_20190924_010558.bak' WITH FILE = 1, MOVE N'Testing' TO N'D:\MSSQL\DATA\Testing.mdf', MOVE N'Testing_log' TO N'L:\MSSQL\LOGS\Testing_log.ldf', NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 1, maxtransfersize=65537
```

Version

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU16) (KB4508218) - 14.0.3223.3 (X64)
>   Jul 12 2019 17:43:08 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
>   Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0
>    (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Does it happen with any backup you try to restore or only with this `M:\MSSQL\My_FULL_Backup_20190924_010558.bak`?

Comment: It happens with this particular database backup only all other backups from the same server works fine.

Comment: What happens when you omit the maxtransfersize or use maxtransfersize of 1MB (1048576) ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU16) (KB4508218) - 14.0.3223.3 (X64)   Jul 12 2019 17:43:08   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: I'm restoring from Prod to QA: Prod is Enterprise (same version) while QA is Develper Edition.

Comment: Also this is the first time I have this kind of issue, this particular database was restoring fine every other time before this issue.

Comment: The maxtransfer size value I took from the backup script as one of the post on stack overflow suggested it.

Comment: @Randi, here's the commands I used: USE [master] RESTORE DATABASE [XXXXX_Testing_20190910] FROM DISK = N'M:\MSSQL\USE1-PRD-CL4$Entreprise_AG2_Testing_FULL_20190924_010558.bak' WITH FILE = 1, MOVE N'Testing' TO N'D:\MSSQL\DATA\Testing.mdf', MOVE N'Testing_log' TO N'L:\MSSQL\LOGS\Testing_log.ldf', NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 1, maxtransfersize=65537 GO

Comment: Here's the result for RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  DISK

Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Read on "M:\MSSQL\BACKUPS\USE1-PRD-CL4$Entreprise_AG2\Testing\FULL\USE1-PRD-CL4$Entreprise_AG2_MyAbsorb-NA_Xcel_Testing_FULL_20190924_010558.bak" failed: 1101(A tape access reached a filemark.)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.